# Mixins: Having trouble with implementation

Tags: css, less, mixins

IS it possible to choose only border-top from this mixins. 
For now I need only top border, but want to collect them to use therefore. I guess will be wrong to use separate mixins for each side border,

```
 .bordered(@top-width: 1px, @top-color: #fff, @bottom-color: #fff) { 
     border-top: @top-width solid @top-color; 
     border-left: @top-width solid @left-color; 
     border-right: @top-width solid @right-color; 
     border-bottom: @top-width solid @bottom-color; }
```

I want to get this output using the same mixins for both

```
.class1{border-top:6px solid red;}
.class2{border-bottom:1px solid white;}
```

Thanks

Comment: creating such a mixin would be counter-productive, since the `border` it wouldn't achieve anything that couldn't take the same time as "normal" css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a mixin where you pass in the border type that you want.  This way you could just have one mixin that you call multiple times.

This mixin uses property interpolation which is available in Less v1.6+

http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-properties

```
.border(@property; @value){
  border-@{property}: @value;       
}

.bacon {
  .border(top; 1px solid black);
}

// Outputs
.bacon {
  .border-top: 1px solid black;
}
```